# How to Center Forest Diagram as a Whole?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, forest

Does anybody know how to center the diagram drawn by the package 'forest', as a whole?
I tried putting the forest inside of a float along with `\centering` and it worked, but I was wondering if there is an alternative way of achieving it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
    \begin{forest}
      for tree={align=center}
      [opencv\_storage
        [cascade
          [height]
          [width]
          [stageNum]
          [stages
            [\textbf{\_}
              [maxWeakCount]
              [stageSthreshold]
              [weakClassifier
                [\textbf{\_}
                  [internalNodes]
                  [leafValues]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
          [...]
          [features
            [\textbf{\_}
              [rects
                [\textbf{\_}]
              ] 
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    \end{forest}
  \end{figure}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: in your mwe (minimal working example) you forgot on `\end{figure}` ... you diagram is perfectly horizontal centered in text area. to see this, for test add in preamble `\usepackage{showframe}`, which will show page layout. welcome to tex.se

Comment: If you don't need the `figure` to float, you can just wrap the `forest` environment in `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the code @Zarko
Oh I forgot to mention that I already tried using `\begin{centering}...\end{centering}` , while writing this comment I realized my mistake... it should be`\begin{CENTER}` not `centering`. Thanks @AlanMunn

Comment: @Human, but your diagram, as is presented in your mwe, is horizontally centered. do you make a test with `showframe`? please, clarify, what is actually your problem!

Comment: @Zarko My actual problem was finding an alternative way of achieving the same result as my posted code without the use of a float like `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}`.
@AlanMunn commented the answer, but afaik I can't accept a comment as an answer. I could however post an answer and refer to this comment.

Comment: @Human, i see. your question is solved by comment, but let us wait for while, if Allan will write an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no need to put the diagram in a floating environment. You can instead wrap it in a `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` environment.